# Node Generators: Using yield at top-level

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a job, which reuses modules from my express app which strongly relies on node-harmony. (And which works nicely), but I don't know how to use generators at "top-level".

So I have this file job.js

```
var locator = require('./../locatorSetup');
yield locator.connect(); // returns a promise
console.log('connected');
```

Which I start by calling

```
node --harmony job.js
```

Unfortunately I get:

```
yield locator.connect();
      ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

What's the recommend way of doing this?

P.S. I'm using Bluebird as my promise library..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. `yield` can only be used within a generator function.

Consider using [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) to execute generator functions at a top level, like so:

```
co(function *() {
  yield locator.connect();
});
```

`co` returns a promise that you can then use to track the completion of the passed generator function.

Comment: ok thanks. 
Using bluebird it would then look like this:
Promise.coroutine(function*(){
 yield locator.connect();
 console.log('connected');
})();